# Pagination, wrong amount of results on first page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm making news website, and I have mysql db with field "time" like 1533074400

Everything is ok if I just print results from query, but if I want to print only news older than today, I get in result only 2 instead of 5 news on first page. Remaining 3 are on the second page.

The problem is with query, if I receive let's say I have in my database 10 results and only 7 of them are past news, so when I filter them descending by

```
if ($today > news_date)
```

I get 2 news on first page (the remaining 3 are invisible future news, blocked by code above) and the rest 5 news on second page. So my question is, what to do to get it properly: 5 news on first page and remaining 2 on second page?

```
$results_per_page = 5;


if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = 1;}
else {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}


$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

$sql='SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$today = strtotime("now");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $news_date = $row[1];

    if ($today > $news_date) {
        echo HTML;
     }
}

$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
  echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
}
```

Comment: is the problem that not the right entities are coming from database of the `if ($today > $news_date)`?

Comment: So to confirm, when on `page=1`, the value for `first_result = 0`, and `results_per_page = 5`. I recommend you try looking at what rows you get without the `LIMIT ...` attached to the query just to make sure you are even getting that many rows.

Comment: might be a simple as `$today >= $news_date` ..?

Comment: @Jek without LIMIT it works fine, but I receive all 7 results on first page, I need 5 on first page and 2 on second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM news WHERE time < '.time().' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
//Note: time() is an equivalent to strtotime("now")
```

If you're doing pagination in MySQL you should also do your filtering inside MySQL.

[Edit: Additional explanation] If you paginate in MySQL and then filter in PHP you'll have weird instances like this crop up because MySQL doesn't know where you're intending to actually start from.  In this particular example if you have a lot of future-dated items you could actually end up with several blank pages of results pages before you start to see entries.

[Edit edit:] Also, if you do this, you'll no longer need the `if` check in your PHP loop as MySQL will have already done that.